# Error al leer csv en Jupyter Notebook desde VSCode o Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, vscode, jupyter, google-colab

Agradeceré de antemano me puedan ayudar u orientar en cómo resolver la correcta lectura del dataset.

1. **Código a utilizar**:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('All_ViewingActivity.csv', index_col=0, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
df1[5]
```

2. **Código de salida con error**:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, aquí -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data puedes encontrar varias posibles soluciones para tu problema. Una de las respuestas menciona que el error puede deberse a que al leer esa línea de tu documento (la 26), el parseador esté encontrando dos campos cuando solo espera uno. ¿Qué hay en esa línea que la distinga de las otras?